# Converting NA's to factor in r

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I want to convert all the NA's in one column (and only one column) of my data frame into "non-PA" instead.  The class of the column is factor.

In the past I've successfully used:

```
df$column[is.na(df$column)] <- "non-PA"
```

But for some reason this time I get this error message:

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(management.points$management),
 value = c(NA, : invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I've tried converting the column to characters and various other ways around it but I still get the same error message.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the part of the code generating this particular error

Comment: Well its the code in my question (df$column[is.na(df$column)] <- "non-PA") but obviously its customised for my code so my dataframe is called "fire" and the column is "management"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to turn the column into a character vector first:

```
df$column <- as.character(df$column)
df$column[is.na(df$column)] <- "non-PA"
df$column <- factor(df$column)
```

The error happens because you cannot input a value in a factor if it is not already a level of that factor.

One potential downside (from @docendo's comment) is that this may remove unused factor levels. To keep them, you could just add "non_PA" to the levels instead of transforming to character:

```
levels(df$column) <- union(levels(df$column), "non_PA")
df$column[is.na(df$column)] <- "non-PA"
```

Comment: As I said in my question, converting the column to character was the first thing I tried but I still get the same error message.  The hybrid solution with @docendo works though.  Thanks guys!  I've marked it as answered.